# for loop doesn't end when condition is met

Tags: c++, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
for(it = gameObjects.begin();it!=gameObjects.end();it++){
    it->second->update(frameTime);
    if(it->second->getSprite()->GetPosition().y > 500){
        std::cout << "Removing enemy" << std::endl;
        std::map<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>::iterator itor = Remove(it->second->getName());
        if(itor!=gameObjects.end()){
            std::cout << "itor doesn't equal" << std::endl;
            it=itor;
        }else{
            std::cout << "itor = end" << std::endl;
            it=itor;
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as `itor = end` is printed, it errors - "map set iterator not incrementable". I thought the for loop should end before it increments again, as `it!=gameObjects.end()` will be false after this. Adding a `break` in the else statement resolves the problem.

Why doesn't it work without the `break`? I'm assuming it's something to do with when the iterator is incremented compared to when the condition is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume correct.  The iterator is incremented at the end of the loop, and then the condition is checked.

So after "itor = end" is printed, it gets incremented to `gameObjects.end()++` which of course is not valid.  You could get around by checking for `itor == gameObjects.end()` inside the loop, and then breaking.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, you're better just removing the ++it from the loop, to avoid skipping over the element after a removed element.  For example:

```
for( it = gameObjects.begin(); it!=gameObjects.end(); ) {
    ...
    if(it->second->getSprite()->GetPosition().y > 500) {
        it = Remove( it->second->getName() );
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's still a problem here. After `it=itor;` and `it++` you just skipped one element. If there is ever a need to remove two in a row, the code will miss the second one.

Comment: Sorry, but it is still a bit tricky. If you delete the very first element, you cannot decrement the iterator (because it will be == `begin()`). The standard is to remove `it++` from the `for` and then *either* remove an element or increment the iterator.

Comment: @BoPersson Ah yeah, thanks for pointing that out.  Clearly wasn't paying as much attention to my example as I was to the initial problem.  Fixed now (I hope)

Answer (score 2):

for loop first performs the statement (increments the value) then checks the condition. the problem is that for-loop tries to increment the iterator after it has reached the end of the map.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::map<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>::iterator itor = Remove(it->second->getName());
.
.
.
it=itor;
```

is your problem.

At some point in time the remove statement removes the last item from `gameObjects` and then you do `it=itor`, setting it to the last item in `gameObjects` without checking your looping condition.  `for` loops increment at the end of the loop for `++` so then you're past the end of `gameObjects`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can do with out the console output you could simplify the loop a bit and simply do as below:

```
for(it = gameObjects.begin();it!=gameObjects.end();){
    it->second->update(frameTime);
    it = it->second->getSprite()->GetPosition().y > 500 
         ? Remove(it->second->getName()); 
         : it++;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know the syntax for that in C++ but I did try something along those lines before reverting back

Comment: @PigHead The last statement of the body could also be places in the loop header making the body a one-liner but I personally find this easier to read than have such a long statement in the loop header